# "Passed all exams in the first term"?

Tags: phrase-requests

How can I say in English that students have passed all of their exams in the shortest period, that is, the first time exams were scheduled (only the first examination term was used)?

Comment: Would "at first try" be adapt/correct?

Comment: I'm looking for something more formal. Would that be OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't find the following particularly informal:

> They passed all their exams on the first try

You could also go with one of the following if they better suit your tastes:

> They passed all their exams the first time they were offered.
>
> They passed all their exams during their earliest opportunities.

Or you could turn it around:

> None of the students needed a second attempt at any of their exams.

Comment: "They passed all their exams during their earliest opportunities." sounds wrong to me. Taking an exam may involve an arduous hour or three, but passing (or failing) an exam is an instantaneous event. "They passed all their exams at the earliest opportunity." doesn't sound so wrong to me, but I don't think it has quite the right meaning, either (and it's probably technically wrong to mix up the plural exams with the singular opportunity). Overall I would stay away from either of these variants. "on the first try" or "the first time they were offered" are both much clearer.

Comment: I actually inserted "passed all of their exams in the first scheduled term". I'm yet to see if there will be any corrections.

Answer (score 2):

"Each student passed all their exams on their first attempt."

Answer (score 0):

All students obtained first time passes in their exams.